# how to deduce template multiple variadic parameters?

Tags: c++, c++20

How to deduce template multiple variadic parameters and using as std::tuple as following code ?
when compile, gets "'f': function does not take 5 arguments" error.

```
#include <tuple>

struct Type1 {
    int v = 0;
};

struct Type2 {
    int v = 0;
};

template <typename ..._t1, typename ..._t2>
void f(
    _t1...  t1,
    _t2...  t2) {
    // t1 as a, b, c
    // t2 as d, e

    auto    x = std::tuple<_t1...>(t1...);
    auto    y = std::tuple<_t2...>(t2...);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Type1 a, b, c;
    Type2 d, e;

    // |-- _t1 --| |-- _t2 --|
    f(   a, b, c,     d, e); // 'f': function does not take 5 arguments

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How the compiler should decide if the first variadic set should take 2 and the last should take 3 parms, or even 1/4 or 0/5???

Comment: Msvc is wrong to reject the (fixed) code[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o8GGfznhd). But the actual split is not your expectation as only `_t2` is deducible, so `_t1` is empty pack, and `_t2` got `a, b, c, d, e`. `f<T1, T1, T1>(a, b, c, d, e);` would have your expected split.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to unambiguously deduce `_t1` and `_t2` from the 5 parameters you pass to the function. The compiler cannot know if `0` or all `5` of the parameters belong to `_t1` or `_t2`.

This is much simpler if the function has tuple arguments:

```
#include <tuple>

struct Type1 { int v = 0; };    
struct Type2 { int v = 0; };

template <typename... _t1, typename... _t2>
void f( std::tuple<_t1...>  t1, std::tuple<_t2...>  t2) {}

int main() {
    Type1 a, b, c;
    Type2 d, e;    
    f(std::make_tuple(a, b, c),std::make_tuple( d, e));   
}
```

This is also a way to go for the more general question:

> how to deduce template multiple variadic parameters?

If you wrap them in a tuple (or other variadic template) you can get both packs deduced. If you don't like `std::make_tuple` you can follow the suggestion of Jarod42 and instead use

> ```
> template <typename T1, typename T2> 
> void f( std::initializer_list<t1>, std::initializer_list<t2>)
> ```

However, this assumes that there are only two different types involved. Perhaps thats what you wanted in the first place.

Comment: "It is not possible to deduce" -> "There is not a *unique* deduction"

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number,  you are right but for the code complexity I don not want to use std::make_tuple in my real code.  Do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: @Caleth, actually it is easy those a,b,c are type _t1 :) followings type _t2... if we can do template <_t1... t1, _t2... t2>

Comment: @VeNToR not sure what complexity you refer to. This is the simple solution.

Comment: @VeNToR *you* want it to be `_t1 = Type1, Type1, Type1` and `_t2 = Type2, Type2`. How does the language know that? [The rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) say that `_t1` is a non-deduced context, and "If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails."

Comment: Currently, the split is done as 0/5 as only last parameter pack is deducible. `f<T1, T1, T1>(a, b, c, d, e);` would have the expected split. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a38ce13fffe980e5)

Comment: `template <typename T1, typename T2> void f( std::initializer_list<t1>, std::initializer_list<t2>)` might be more appropriate for grouping same types.

Answer (score 3):

There is a lambda trick to get a succinct syntax:

```
template<typename... T1>
auto f(T1...  t1) {
    return [=](auto... t2) {
        auto x = std::tuple(t1...);
        auto y = std::tuple(t2...);

        // ...
    };
}

Type1 a, b, c;
Type2 d, e;

f(a, b, c)(d, e);
```

Comment: nice one. I think `template<typename... T1> auto f(T1...  t1)` is sufficient. And actually I dont understand why `template<typename... T1, typename... T2> auto f(T1...  t1)` works

Comment: @Evg, it opens another door for me :)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It was a typo. Fixed. Thanks. Intuitively, the fact that a compiler can deduce `T2...` to be an empty pack is not very surprising.

Comment: oh right, the lambda deduces independently via `auto`, so no problem. For some reason i though `T2...` was the types of `t2`